# Getting Internal Error in Subcommand Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've been facing a problem lately with bukkit coding. When I launch the plugin and just type /akitz   **command label or name** it pops up with an Internal Error but when I type /akitz {subcommand} it works fine! everything here basically works fine but just the /akitz   <-- alone when i type it, an error pops up!   here's the code:

```
package me.frostgamersa;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
@Override
public void onEnable() {

}

@Override
public void onDisable() {

}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("akitz")) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0 || args.length < 2) {
            player.sendMessage("§cIncorrect Arguments");

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("legend")) {
                player.sendMessage("§bYou have been Granted §3Legend §bKit!");
                CustomItems.givela(player);
                CustomItems.givels(player);
                player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
                return true;
            }
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("god")) {
                player.sendMessage("§bYou have been Granted §3God §bKit!");
                CustomItems.givega(player);
                CustomItems.givegs(player);
                player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
                return true;
            } else {
                player.sendMessage("§cIncorrect Arguments!");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: You're not closing the if statement `if (args.length == 0 || args.length < 2) {`

Comment: Because you first check if args length is **zero**, and then try to get **first** argument (`if args[0].equals....`) in command without args. So I think console prints ArrayOfBoundsException. Because of any exception occured in `onCommand` method you will see message 'Internal error ...'

Comment: @ItzBenteThePig I have tried that, didn't work! Thank you all for offering to help!

Comment: You can simplify `if (args.length == 0 || args.length < 2)` down to `if (args.length < 2)`: if the length is 0, then it definitely is less than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how command should look like..

```
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    Player p = (Player) sender;

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("akitz")) {

        if (args.length != 1) {

            p.sendMessage("§cIncorrect argument count!");

        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("legend")) {

            p.sendMessage("§bYou got a kit §3Legend");
            CustomItems.givela(p);
            CustomItems.givels(p);
            p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
            return true;

        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("god")) {

            p.sendMessage("§bYou got a kit §3God");
            CustomItems.givega(p);
            CustomItems.givegs(p);
            p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
            return true;

        }

        if (!args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("legend") | !args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("god")) {

            p.sendMessage("§cIncorrect argument!");

        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Also, let your class implement CommandExecutor and add to your onEnable method this..

```
    public void onEnable() {

        getCommand("akitz").setExecutor(this);

}
```

which will register command, just for sure

Answer (score 0):

Spoonfeed incoming:

```
package me.frostgamersa;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
@Override
public void onEnable() {

}

@Override
public void onDisable() {

}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("akitz")) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length < 2) {
            player.sendMessage("§cIncorrect Arguments");
        } else {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("legend")) {
                player.sendMessage("§bYou have been Granted §3Legend §bKit!");
                CustomItems.givela(player);
                CustomItems.givels(player);
                player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
                return true;
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("god")) {
                player.sendMessage("§bYou have been Granted §3God §bKit!");
                CustomItems.givega(player);
                CustomItems.givegs(player);
                player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 64));
                return true;
            } else {
                player.sendMessage("§cIncorrect Arguments!");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend you remove onEnable and onDisable, as those are not required, and since you have nothing in them, it's just using up space that it doesn't need to.

Also, you should check if the sender is a player before casting it, as that could create errors when console executes a command.